# Не устанавливаются куки и сессии

Tags: php, apache, nginx, cookie, сессия

Подскажите решение проблемы -
Архитектура: nginx -> apache

Авторизацию делаю через ajax на скрипт login.php, после успешной авторизации в скрипте login.php должны устанавливаться куки и сессии, но они не ставятся, в логах nginx и apache ошибок нет. В куках прописываю домен и путь.

```
Конфиг nginx
# Перенаправление на back-end
location / {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.10.80:8080/www2/public/;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_connect_timeout 120;
   proxy_send_timeout 120;
   proxy_read_timeout 180;
}
```

Использую фреймворк Codeigniter, код login.php

```
    $this->CI->input->set_cookie(array(
                'name'   => 'auth',
                'value'  => $data,
                'expire' => $ttl
            ));
    $newdata = array(
        'name'  => 'auth',
        'value'  => $data,
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->CI->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Comment: Мало информации. Первое, что приходит в голову - headers already sent, куки надо устанавливать до любого вывода. Второе - ошибки php не всегда пишутся в лог сервера, попробуйте ручками открыть ваш login.php и посмотреть как он себя ведет.

Comment: Это как позвонить травматологу по теле фону, описать перелом и просить что бы он удаленно вам гипс наложил.

Хоть что-то то приложите, хоть какие-то фрагменты кода.

Comment: [http://tsya.ru][]

Comment: Предположу. 
Моя "любимая" ошибка, забывать вписывать строку session_start();
Вы про неё не забыли?

Answer (score 1):

ответы из комментариев:

---

Первое, что приходит в голову - headers already sent, куки надо устанавливать до любого вывода. Второе - ошибки php не всегда пишутся в лог сервера, попробуйте ручками открыть ваш login.php и посмотреть как он себя ведет. – Darth

---

Предположу. Моя "любимая" ошибка, забывать вписывать строку session_start(); Вы про неё не забыли? – Павел Вершинин